# Awk command to replace a substring with a specific value

Tags: awk

I have a flat file which has a phone number in field starting at position 314 till 323. Now I wanted to dummy out that field with `1234567890`.

For this I tried using the below commands and both are throwing error:

```
awk '{var=substr($0,314,10);gsub("[0-9]","1234567890",$var); print}' final_phone.txt >final_phone.txt1
```

> fatal: grow_fields_arr: fields_arr: can't allocate 9849885432 bytes of memory (Cannot allocate memory)

In second case

```
awk 'var=substr($0,314,10) { var = "1234567890" }1' final_phone.txt >final_phone.txt1
```

This worked but the values didn't change. The output remained the same.

Can someone help me with the syntax here?

In the first case I tried to assign the substring to a variable and in `gsub()` I wanted to check for numbers pattern and substitute with `1234567890`.

can someone help me with this

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add i) an example input file and ii) the output you want from that file. It is very hard to help you parse data if you do not show us what we are supposed to parse.

Comment: Asked and answered at https://stackoverflow.com/q/69678703/1745001 an hour before you asked the same question here. Please don't multi-post and please do read the answers you get on any forum where you ask questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to print two substring, one part before that position and another part after that position, something like:

```
$ awk -v dummy='0123456789' -v start=314 -v len=10 '
{ print substr($0, 1, start-1) dummy substr($0, start+len) }' infile >outfile
```

testing:

```
$ awk -v dummy='0123456789' -v start=4 -v len=10 '
{ print substr($0, 1, start-1) dummy substr($0, start+len) }' <<<'0009876543210999'
0000123456789999
```

---

Issue with your command:

1. you are using `$var` instead of `var` in the third argument to the gsub() as it result gsub() to look a field which its number is the value of the `var` which it's a 10digits length field number, so awk tries to gsub() on that field #xxxxxxxxxx but it fails due to memory allocation for reevaluating these very huge number of fields (because when using any field other than `$0` in the third argument to the gsub() it forces awk to rebuild the fields back on default OFS).
2. if we fix the issue #1, then you will replace every single digits in the `var` variable with `1234567890` string.
3. you then used `print` it will print the current line without changes, since you don't do any updates on that.

Comment: I tried the above commands which you provided . In both cases the substring didnt change

Comment: I have redirected to a new file but no luck

Comment: awk -v dummy='1234567890' -v start=314-v len=10 ' { print substr($0, 1, start-1) dummy substr($0, start+len) }' final_phone.txt >final_phone1.txt

Comment: @Nikhil did you just copy&pasting from the answer? why the space after 314 before `-v` is removed? and then make sure your file in Linux text file with newline ending not windows like with CRLF, if it's windows you need to perform a `dos2unix` on your file first

Comment: No when i copied it here it was lost . the command executed well but the output was not as expected

Comment: @Nikhil see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/674384/awk-command-to-replace-a-substring-with-a-specific-value/674390?noredirect=1#comment1272902_674384 and take your action. I don't see then how it doesn't work.  we don't see your expected output then but my given answer is based on what you described and trying to do.

Comment: Excellent answer. `$len`: is length of `$dummy`, `$start` is column position which is starting replacement string.

Answer (score 1):

You can used `sed` instead of `awk` which will be less verbose:

```bsh
$ sed -E 's/^(.{313})[0-9]{10}/\10123456789/' infile
<313 chars>1234567890
```

Comment: I tried this but it completely changed the format of the file

Comment: @Nikhil please **[edit]** the question adding [what is asked here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/674384/awk-command-to-replace-a-substring-with-a-specific-value/674392?noredirect=1#comment1272902_674384)

Answer (score 0):

You could use perl instead of awk.  e.g.

```
perl -p -e 'substr($_,313,10) = "1234567890"' final_phone.txt >final_phone.txt1
```

NOTE: in perl's `substr` function, offsets start from 0 instead of 1 - so offset 313 is the 314th character.  See `perldoc -f substr` for details.